# Dynamic content did not load in boorstrap modal

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I have a bootstrap modal and i'm fetching divs from controller via ajax. When i click on the modal show button the modal appear but these divs did not appear in the modal.
I have to show this dynamic content when modal is open in it.
I have call function updateDocumentType(EmployeeID) when modal open but nothing works for me although i have created selected box when i click on select box this function successfully working.

modal show function

```
function uploadDocument(e) {
        var id = $(e).data("id");
        $("#documentEmpId").val(id);
        $('#documentModal').modal('show');

        updateDocumentType(id);
        $('#DocumentType').on('change', function () {
            updateDocumentType(id);
        });

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/recruitment/documentsData",
            data: {
                id: id,
            },
            async: true,
            beforeSend: function () {
                $('#pageloader').show();
            },
            success: function (response) {
                var type = (response.DocumentType).split(',')
                $("#DocumentType").empty()
                $("#DocumentType").attr('disabled', false);
                for (var i = 0; i < response.poi_array.length; i++) {
                    $("#DocumentType").append("<option value='" + response.poi_array[i].name + "'>" + response.poi_array[i].name + '</option>');
                }
             
            },
            error: function (e) {
                console.log(e.responseText);
            },
            complete: function () {
                $('#pageloader').hide();
            }
        });
    }
```

dynamic content function loading from controller

```
 function updateDocumentType(EmployeeID) {
        var DocumentType = $('#DocumentType').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "/recruitment/updateDocumentType",
            data: {
                EmployeeID: EmployeeID,
                type: 'updateDocumentType',
                DocumentType: DocumentType,
            },
            async: true,
            beforeSend: function () {
                $('#pageloader').show();
            },
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function (response) {
                $('#DocumentType').html(response.result.getDocumentType);
                $('#poi_documents').html(response.result.getDocuments);
                addTippy('.upload');
                addTippy('.edit');
            },
            error: function (e) {
                console.log(e.responseText);
            },
            complete: function () {
                $('#pageloader').hide();
            }
        });

    }
```